# How do I add as editor Dreamweaver to work in GIT?

Tags: git, dreamweaver

How do I add Dreamweaver as the editor in Git?

```
git config --global core.editor???

$ slime README.md
sh.exe": slime: command not found
```

Comment: Where did you find that slime command? As far as I know, it's not part of git.

Comment: Dreamweaver is supposed to automatically support the default-installed Git. See the Adobe article [Using Git in Dreamweaver](https://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/using/git-support.html) and follow it exactly. If this doesn't work for you, please indicate in which step you are getting the problem.

Comment: ew dreamweaver :-/

Comment: No answer to my comment?

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't exactly what your needs require however I found GITWeaver – GIT for Dreamweaver has been good to me in the past plus it also works with Dreamweaver CS6.

> GITWeaver integrates Adobe Dreamweaver with TortoiseGIT; Basically Dreamweaver + GIT
> living together. Nice and Free, what more could you really want!
>
> http://turtleweaver.co.uk/

ChrisMcKee GitHub Repo can be found (https://github.com/ChrisMcKee/gitweaver)

HTH

Answer (score -1):

You can't because there is no git plugin available for dreamweaver like one in eclipse.

Comment: When I try to configure it with Notepad + + I get the same error      $ slime README.md
sh.exe": slime: command not found

Comment: How should I configure or should I put plugin or instruction to recognize the notepad + +??